# strong params issue with attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am upgrading rails application fro **3.2.2** to rails **5.1.4**.
I am having issue with strong params with attr_accessor.

**Console params output: Why i am getting permitted: false**

```
   <ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8/6yMCzyPw==", "journal"=><ActionController::Parameters {"user_id"=>"1", "subject"=>"sdf", 
"body"=>"sdf", "recipients"=>["zzzzz@yahoo.com"]} permitted: false>, "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"journals", "action"=>"create", "assignment_id"=>"9081"} permitted: false>
```

Here is my controller create action: **journals_controller.rb**

```
      def create
        @facility = Facility.find(params[:facility_id])
        @journal = @facility.journals.new(journal_params)
        @journal.save
      end
  private
  def journal_params
    params.require(:journal).permit(:user_id, :body, :recipients, :subject)
  end
```

**journal.rb**

```
  attr_accessor :recipients
```

**journal/views/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@assignments, @journal]  do |f| %>
  <%= form_legend %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>    
  <p>
    <%= f.label :subject %><%= required_field %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :subject, :size => 80 %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><%= required_field %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body, :cols => 80, :rows => 5 %>
  </p>

  <% unless params[:action] == 'edit' %>
        <fieldset>
          <table class="list">
            <% for group in Journal.possible_recipients.in_groups(3, false) %>
              <td>
              <% for recipient in group %>
                <%= check_box_tag "journal[recipients][]", recipient.try(:email) %> <%= bold_assignees_helper recipient %><br />
              <% end %>
              </td>
              <% end %>
          </table>
         </fieldset>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**strong params are permitted, but still getting permitted: false on console**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your permitted parms to allow `array of recipients` like below:

```
def journal_params
  params.require(:journal).permit(:user_id, :body, recipients: [], :subject)
end
```

Let me know if the error persists and i'll try to help you

Comment: Thanks, code is working now, but why console is still displaying permitted: false?

Comment: Would you please restart the server and share the logs again

Answer (score 0):

`permitted = false` is the default unless you call `permit!` to allow all parameter in hash. But it will defeats the use of strong parameter.